# ServiceWorker updatefound event vs waiting worker

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

I'm wondering why [ServiceWorkerRegistration has an `updatefound` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerRegistration/updatefound_event) but no event that fires as soon as Service Worker in the `installed` (not "installing") state.

IMHO `updatefound` is not very useful on itself since it triggers when there is a new Service Worker file found. In that phase, the service worker may still be downloading cache files and might take a few moments until it is ready to be activated.

Depending on the application, it might be too early to display a "refresh to update" message in response to "updatefound". Instead, the client IMHO should wait the new Service Worker to reach the `installing` state:

```js
function handleUpdateReady() {

  // Service Worker ready to be activated (skipWaiting() can be called)
  // Show message to the user.

}


navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js').then(registration => {

  if (registration.waiting) {

    // a new Service Worker is already in the "installed" Phase and waits to be activated.
    handleUpdateReady();

  } else {

    registration.addEventListener('updatefound', () => {

      const newSW = registration.installing;

      newSW.addEventListener('statechange', ev => {

        if (newSW.state === 'installed')
          handleUpdateReady();

      });

    });

  }

});
```

On a slow network this might make a huge difference, because reloading the page while the new Service Worker is still "installing" is useless. On fast networks, one might not notice the difference.

Either I'm missing something or the above sample shows the correct way to deal with Service Worker / App updates **if the app should update as soon as the new version is fully ready**.

It makes me wonder why the relatively complicated code above is necessary when the spec could just have provided a `registration.addEventListener('updateready', ...)` or something like that for a relatively common use case. Since there is no such event, I'm wondering if I'm missing a simpler solution.